# Sed to find line number restricted to a range of line numbers

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed to find the line number of a string in a text file. The following code works perfectly.

```
variable1=$(sed -n '/asdf/ =' $file);
```

The problem I am having is when I try to limit the search to a range of line numbers. In the example below, I am trying to limit it to lines 5 through 10. Let's say "asdf" exists on line 7. I am getting no value set to variable2.

```
variable2=$(sed -n '5,10 /asdf/ =' $file);
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how with `awk`:

```bsh
$ cat file
qwer
asdf
zxcv
qwer
asdf
zxcv
qwer
asdf
zxcv 

$ awk '/asdf/ && NR>=5 && NR<=10 {print NR}' file
5
8
```

If you want to stop after the first match just `exit` the script and use command substitution to store the value in a variable:

```bsh
$ awk '/asdf/ && NR>=5 && NR<=10 {print NR; exit}' file
5

$ var=$(awk '/asdf/ && NR>=5 && NR<=10 {print NR; exit}' file)

$ echo $var
5
```

Comment: Can you expand on that? How do I put the first result (5 in your example) into a variable?

Comment: You can put all the conditions outside of the action block: `awk '5<=NR && NR<=10 && /asdf/ {print NR}'`

Answer (score 3):

your sed line is very close. see below (borrowed sudo_O's input example:

```
kent$  echo "qwer
asdf
zxcv
qwer
asdf
zxcv
qwer
asdf
zxcv"| sed -n '5,10 {/asdf/=}'  
5
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
variable2=$(sed -n '5,10 {/asdf/=}' $file);
```